# SQL To Search Number/Currency Values in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, search, decimal

I've built a web application that has a small search facility. As part of my search, I offer the users the option to search by dollar amounts. I did some searching around and didn't find any solid examples or advice other than the "LIKE" clause doesn't operate on numbers in SQL, so my question is:

Can someone provide an example of an correct SQL statement to search against numbers with decimals in a database. For example, if some inputs 5234.32 as a currency search, I'd want the results to return any records whose "amount" column is 5xxx.xx. If the user entered 64.58, I'd want to return any records whose "amount" column is 6x.xx

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need arithmetic operations for this. You may namage to do it with `LIKE` but it's not going to be nice.

Comment: Please understand that [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505) - we would like you to show us what you have tried and explain where you are stuck before we answer the question.

Comment: @Oded, no one asked for research. I'll just communicate with those who were kind enough to offer suggestions that provides some direction.

Comment: Then why did you even respond to me? I believe the question shows no research effort of any sort. There is no mention of what was attempted and where you are stuck. The kind of question I would like to see is described in [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Opinions are like rectums, everyone has one.

Answer (score 2):

The search for `5xxx.xx` is the same as search for `5000 <= field AND field < 6000`.

I recommend against truncating the field, since it will prevent the DBMS from using any existing index. A range scan shown above should be very efficient assuming there is an index on `field`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, you can probably do this:

```
-- Oracle
WHERE TRUNC(amount, -decimals) = TRUNC(:user_input, -decimals)

-- MySQL
WHERE TRUNCATE(amount, -decimals) = TRUNCATE(:user_input, -decimals)
```

By `decimals` I mean the number of digits to the left of the decimal points that you want to keep, i.e.

```
TRUNC(5234.32, -3) = 5000.00
TRUNC(64.58, -1)   = 60.00
```

A silly way to discover the decimals in SQL would be this:

```
-- Oracle
LENGTH(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(amount)))

-- MySQL
LENGTH(CAST(TRUNCATE(amount) AS CHAR))
```

Of course this might turn out to be slow, as [Branko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583898/521799) mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to varchar and use the like?

Otherwise you may use arithmetic operations like @ypercube stated.

Comment: Thanks! This was my initial approach, but I wanted to make see if there was a more correct way to do this. Thanks @aF.

Comment: @MarkJohnsII you should accept answers. Or someday nobody will answer. Check how to do it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work